# Usage of custom class items in mainpage? Metro app

Tags: listview, listbox, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I want to define a custom class which has, an image and a textblock.

Custom Class

```
<Page Height="100" Width="500"
    x:Class="SQLite.Custom"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SQLite"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"> 

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Image Name="img" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="67" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="91"/>
        <TextBlock Name="txtBlk" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="177,22,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="45" Width="264"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Now I want to add them back to a listview in my mainpage.

```
Custom clb = new Custom();
listviews.Items.Add(clb);
```

I have tried doing so, but failed in many cases. can't access 
clb.img or clb.txtBlk .

Kindly need some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have not tagged whether your question is XAML or WinJS related but let me point you to an [Article](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-item-templates-7d74826f/sourcecode?fileId=50887&pathId=1185249808) which shows an example of how to create a list-view item template in WinJS:

```
<div id="regularListIconTextTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" style="display: none"> 
    <div class="regularListIconTextItem"> 
            <img src="#" class="regularListIconTextItem-Image" data-win-bind="src: picture" /> 
        <div class="regularListIconTextItem-Detail"> 
            <h4 data-win-bind="innerText: title"></h4> 
            <h6 data-win-bind="innerText: text"></h6> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the MSDN [Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate) for XAML ListView item template.

Comment: @WiniP I have included a reference to XAML item template as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, all I want to do is to get that custom class onto my listview. While accessing the customclass' elements.